# Dataset management: What are some strategies/solutions for efficiently storing datasets with their versions?

Tags: dataset, data, version-control

**The problem**: I've N classification models (independent), for each of these N models, I've different versions (eg: V<sub>0</sub>, V<sub>1</sub>, ..., V<sub>final_production</sub>,V<sub>experimental</sub>). I'm looking for a way to store my datasets efficiently on the cloud (for redudency).

*Note: We're not talking about BigData here.*

**Current Solution**: Created a private GitHub repo. Made N directories and inside, pushed different dataset versions as different files.

Are there better solutions for this (because I feel VCS is an overkill for this problem)?

Comment: how much/why is data changing from model to model? Also, as a rule of thumb: you shouldn't get in the practice of committing data to git.

Comment: Each independent models are independent programs serving a different purpose. If not VCS, what are the alternative strategies?

Comment: use a database to store your data with auditing tables to track when records get changed, and track your model training code from the data-pull forward in VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used my existing directory structure with [Git LFS](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs) and it works well.

Here are the advantages I got by using Git LFS other than the alternative solutions.

- **It saves space**: Since Git LFS manages my dataset files (100MB to 1GB) with pointers and keeping only the minimum in the local memory.
- **It works seamlessly with a git enabled repository**: I was planning to use some storage solution (like Amazon S3) specific for my datasets. But I would have to make extra efforts to manage multiple version and keep my dataset files in sync.